# Is lighting needed for a 3D model in blender if you are going to import it into unity?

Tags: light, import, unity

I'm making a 3D character in blender who has a hood over his head and I positioned the light in blender so you wouldn't be able to see his face because of the shadow of the hoodie, if I import this model into unity will the light effect that I used in blender be removed off the model.

Comment: No it is not. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 1):

depends on how you import it. you could import the blend file, that includes the lights, or you could export the model as an FBX.
either way, if you only place the model in the scene, the light won't be included, except if you place the entire blend file in the scene.
or you could parent the light to the model... if you want it to be included, but i recommend using the lighting from unity itself